# Angular 8 Router in a subdirectory

Tags: angular8

I'm working on Angular 8 project that I have to put inside a sub-directory on a server.
On index.html I have `<base href="/subdirectory/">`
And on app-routing

```
 {
       path: '',
       component: HomeComponent
       },
      {
        path: 'aaa/:id/:lang',
        component: FirstStoryComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'bbb/:id/:lang',
        component: SecondStoryComponent
      },
```

url `http://www.testurl.com/subdirectory/aaa/46/en`

I can navigate between component alright if I start from HomeComponent first and use internal links like buttons or `<a></a>` tags. But if I create a link from another web to navigate directly to FirstStoryComponent with parameters. The url, exactly the same url, will disappear right away and the page is not loaded as if the url is incorrect or the page doesn't receive parameters.
This is the ActivatedRoute

```
this.actRoute.params.subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.ID = +params['id'];
          this.lang = params['lang'];
        }
      );
```

I also tried

```
this.ID = +this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
```

I need to be able to link from another website.

Can someone give me some guide please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> The basic rule in an Angular app (like in every Single Page App in
> general) is:
>
> The server has to be configured in a way that it serves the index.html
> instead of a 404 page in each case a url is requested which the server
> doesn’t know, so that Angular's router can handle the correct routing
> (see my explanations below).
>
> How to achieve this in detail depends on the type of your server and
> is beyond the scope of this course. Please have a look at this article
> of the official docs (or get help on stackoverflow for your individual
> server) ...
>
> → https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration
>
> ... and the Academind article here ...
>
> →
> https://academind.com/learn/angular/angular-q-a/#how-to-fix-broken-routes-after-deployment
>
> ng serve does this automatically, and for local tests I've installed
> http-server-spa globally (npm i -g http-server-spa), for easily
> serving the content from the dist folder by running http-server-spa
> dist/ inside the project (on root level, like ng serve).
>
> ---
>
> For testing a built project locally you can use http-server-spa:
>
> Install it with npm i http-server-spa.
>
> Then serve the built app with http-server-spa dist/
>
> ---
>
> In a Single Page Application the server only serves some static files
> in the beginning (an almost empty index.html and some js bundles).
> Everything, routing included, has to be managed in the browser.
>
> Therefore, if the server gets a request for my-domain.com/something,
> it always has to serve the index.html (simply since the server doesn't
> know any other html file, and redirecting to a 404 page would be bad
> in this case, since then the app wouldn't be served at all). Then the
> Angular router (which is loaded with the bundles attached to
> index.html) can modify index.html in a way that the user sees the
> /something content resp. is redirected to a "not found" component of
> the Angular app.
>
> This is not specific to Angular, but it would be the same principle if
> you would implement routing in an SPA manually with history.pushState.

I was given this advise by **Jost Schmithals** of **Udemy** Angular The Complete Guide

And after some searches on this forum, I found an answer.

I have to put this in my .htaccess subdirectory and now it works.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```